# Como agrego una función a un botón que esta siendo creado dentro de otro botón?

Tags: java, eventos, interfaz-gráfica

Ayer formule una pregunta sobre como podía crear un botón accionando otro y ya encontré la forma, pero ahora mi problema es que no se como hago para agregarle su funcionamiento, Verán, Algunos botones ya vendrán programados y cada uno de ellos tendrá como texto el nombre de la persona(Instalador) y su función sera que al dar click, Me copie automáticamente su id, y pues con el tiempo irán surgiendo nuevos instaladores y me encantara poder hacer mi programa apto para personas normales y pues pienso agregar un botón aparte de los de los instaladores para que puedan agregar mas y mas, y necesito que cada botón creado por la persona tenga las funciones similares a las demás.

He aquí mi limitación, No se donde o como iría su función:

```
private void agregarInstaladorActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
    JButton nuevoInstalador = new JButton("Nuevo Boton");
    panel.add(nuevoInstalador);
    validate();
}
```

Y he aqui mi codigo entero:

```
class facturacion_1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Ventana v = new Ventana();
    v.setVisible(true);
    v.setSize(1280,720);
    v.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

}
```

}

```
class Ventana extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

JPanel panel;
JButton andresTorres, alexanderHernandez, eduardoRuiz, jorgeFley, agregarInstalador;
public Ventana(){

    panel = new JPanel();
    //Instaladores
    andresTorres = new JButton("Andres Torres");
    alexanderHernandez = new JButton("Alexander Hernandez");
    eduardoRuiz = new JButton("Eduardo Ruiz");
    jorgeFley = new JButton("Jorge Fley");
    agregarInstalador = new JButton("Agregar Instaladores");
    //End

    add(panel);

    panel.add(andresTorres);
    panel.add(alexanderHernandez);
    panel.add(eduardoRuiz);
    panel.add(jorgeFley);
    panel.add(agregarInstalador);

    setTitle("Asistente de Facturacion");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(this.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    andresTorres.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
            andresTorresActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });


    alexanderHernandez.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
            alexanderHernandezActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    eduardoRuiz.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
            eduardoRuizActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jorgeFley.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
            jorgeFleyActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    agregarInstalador.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
            agregarInstaladorActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
}

private void agregarInstaladorActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
    JButton nuevoInstalador = new JButton("Nuevo Boton");
    panel.add(nuevoInstalador);
    validate();
}

private void andresTorresActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
        String myString = "aqui va su identificacion";
        StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(myString);
        Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
        clipboard.setContents(stringSelection, null);
    }

private void alexanderHernandezActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
        String myString = "aqui va su identificacion";
        StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(myString);
        Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
        clipboard.setContents(stringSelection, null);
    }

private void eduardoRuizActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
        String myString = "aqui va su identificacion";
        StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(myString);
        Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
        clipboard.setContents(stringSelection, null);
    }

private void jorgeFleyActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
        String myString = "aqui va su identificacion";
        StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(myString);
        Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
        clipboard.setContents(stringSelection, null);
    }

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}
```

}

¡Se les agradece de antemano!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema de base que tienes es que tienes que evitar poner un código duplicado para cosas que realmente solo varían por el valor de una variable.

Hacer una clase listener diferente para cada elemento de la lista, cuando lo único que cambia es el nombre, es inmantenible. ¿Crees que Microsoft o Boeing va modificando el código de sus aplicaciones cada vez que contratan o despiden a alguien?

Lo que tienes que hacer es separar entre los datos y comportamiento.
Por ejemplo:

```
public class InstaladorActionListener implements ActionListener {

    private String nombre;

    public InstaladorActionListener(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
       StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(this.nombre);
       Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
       clipboard.setContents(stringSelection, null);
    }
}
```

Y a la hora de hacer añadir un botón:

```
private void agregarInstaladorActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
    JButton nuevoInstalador = new JButton("Nuevo Boton");
    panel.add(nuevoInstalador);
    nuevoInstalador.addActionListener(
      new InstaladorActionListener("Nuevo instalador"));

    validate();
}
```

Naturalmente, también puedes usar esa forma de trabajar para poner los valores por defecto; de hecho no deberías tener la información "hard-codeada" en el código sino que tendrías que sacar esa información de una fuente de datos, ya sea una base de datos, un fichero de texto o un servicio web. **Tu código no debe variar porque cambien datos que por su naturaleza son variables**.